# Resizing window make disappear SVG sprites in Chrome/Safari (because of media queries)

Tags: google-chrome, svg, responsive-design, safari, rendering

I am using an svg technique to insert SVG using stacking technique

Stacking SVG Reference:
http://simurai.com/blog/2012/04/02/svg-stacks/

I insert the SVG as

```
<embed class="vector vec1" src="/img/sprite.svg#lottery-ticket" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
```

because if I use the `<img>` tag, it will not render in Safari.

The SVG it is filled with many svg code inside, everyone with their own ID and Viewbox. The top of the svg is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="icon" class="icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

When I load in every browser IE9+, Chrome, Safari and Firefox, everythings works and render no problem. But when I resize manually the window, the SVG images they disappear.
I am sure that the problem is related to a change that I have in my media queries when I reach a particular breakpoint.
I am testing and removing various pieces of the code, and I cannot find the reason other than a problem of rendering of svg at the changes of the parents containers divs that they resize because the whole structure of the website it is built with responsive design in mind.

Any idea or suggestions or what I can try out to see what is the problem? does someone knows if Chrome behave erratically like that?

Thank you for your help. I do not put the code only because there is a lot of code to insert and it is quite a lot of it and split in many small pieces.

**UPDATE**

I think that the problem is related with my Fluid Column system. I switch between columns that have display:table-cell and float:left, to display:block and float:none. I am keeping testing and narrowing down the problem.